# Обращение к динамически создаваемым элементам формы из класса

Tags: c#, winforms

Как получить доступ из класса к динамически создаваемым элементам формы (в моем случае textBox)?

Вот так я создаю элементы:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(input); i++)
{
    panel1.Controls.Add(new TextBox()
    {
        Name = i.ToString(),
        Location = new Point(54, yTextBox_n = yTextBox_n + 35),
        Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 14.25f)
    });

    panel1.Controls.Add(new Label()
    {
        Name = i.ToString(),
        Location = new Point(8, yLabel_n = yLabel_n + 35),
        Text = "n" + i,
        Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 14.25f, FontStyle.Italic)
    });
}
```

у меня есть алгоритм. я ввожу с формы нужные данные и выводятся вот эти динамически создаваемые элементы. затем я ввожу в них данные и эти данные мне надо передать в класс алгоритм
как передать их?

вот такой класс. Он совсем не доделанный. Он должен получать динамически создаваемые элементы

```
class Class_Algorithm
{
    int[,] Matrix;
    int L;
    int N;

    public Class_Algorithm(int[,] matrix, int l, int n)
    {
        Matrix = matrix;
        L = l;
        N = n;
    }

    public void Algorithm()
    {
        int k = 1;
        int q = 1;

        for (int d = 0; d < L; d++)
        {
            int m = 1;
            int z = 1;
            int[] r = new int[N];

            for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    r[i] += Matrix[i, j];
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Передайте их параметром )) А вообще - имхо - не красиво так делать. Если возникает такая потребность - значит проблемы с архитектурой. Если о последней речи не идет - читаем заново первое предложение.

Comment: _в любом другом классе_ в каком например?

Comment: что за класс алгоритм? где объявляется его переменная? какие параметры принимает функция которую надо вызвать?

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)`

Answer (score 2):

Это в самой форме куда добавляется этот элемент.

```
this.Controls.Find("ControlName", false);
```

Если из другого класса,  то в параметре передайте Ui компонент в который добавляется динамически контрол. Это на самом деле плохой способ, выложите код!

В вашем случае не вижу ничего плохого, если добавить в класс формы функцию, которая будет в конструктор алгоритма передавать нужное значение.

```
public void GetTextByDynamicCreateTextBox(string name)
        {
           string param =  panel1.Controls.Find(name, false).FirstOrDefault().Text;
           Algorytm alg = new Algorytm(param);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private Dictionary<int, TextBox> dynamicTextboxes = new Dictionary<int, TextBox>();

private string TextByIndex(int index)
{
  string result = "";
  if (dynamicTextboxes.ContainsKey(index))
    result = dynamicTextboxes[index].Text;
  return result;
}    


dynamicTextboxes.Clear();
for (int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(input); i++)
{
    TextBox box = new TextBox()
    {
        Name = "textbox_" + i.ToString(),
        Location = new Point(54, yTextBox_n = yTextBox_n + 35),
        Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 14.25f)
    };
    dynamicTextboxes[i] = box;
    panel1.Controls.Add(box);

    panel1.Controls.Add(new Label()
    {
        Name = "label_" + i.ToString(),
        Location = new Point(8, yLabel_n = yLabel_n + 35),
        Text = "n" + i,
        Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 14.25f, FontStyle.Italic)
    });
}
```

Comment: Можно узнать на какой вопрос вы отвечаете?

Comment: @FoggyFinder я отвечаю на вопрос "как передать их?"

Comment: Не скажу за автора вопроса, но мне ответ не понятен. Более того, считаю, что передавать элементы формы в другие классы плохая практика.

Comment: @FoggyFinder У меня возникло впечатление, что у ТС есть трудности с получением значений из динамически созданных TextBox'ов. Я предлагаю хранить ссылки на них в контейнере (члене класса формы).

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял. Тогда, полагаю, нужно дополнить ответ добавив метод, который преобразует информацию из `dynamicTextboxes` в `int[,]`

Comment: @FoggyFinder Преобразовывать информацию в int[,]? А по какому принципу? Об этом точно автор не спрашивал!  Просто тут был создан независимый контейнер, что является хорошим тоном, но в данной задаче мне кажется это избыточным.

Comment: @Yury Bakharev, Спрашивал, вот цитата: "затем я ввожу в них данные и эти данные мне надо передать в класс алгоритм как передать их?
вот такой класс. ". Этот класс имеет следующий конструктор: `Class_Algorithm(int[,] matrix, int l, int n)`. А те динамически создаваемые элементы (`TextBox `) предназначены для ввода значений элементов матрицы.

Comment: @FoggyFinder ну можно догадаться конечно, но это будет только догадка, а если там будут считаться миноры или определитель методом Крамера, там нужны не все данные с матрицы. Вопрос был о получение "кастомного" TextBox, который создается динамически.

Comment: @Yury Bakharev, разве это имеет значение?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Из кода в вопросе - с одномерным циклом создания контролов - невозможно понять, как их значениями заполняется двумерный массив.

Comment: Согласен, можно только догадываться. Так что предлагаю дождаться ответа от @Mariya